# Is my Product ID my Product Key

Tags: windows-7, product-key, product-id

I wanted to run windows 7 in virtualbox, so I needed a product key to download the iso. I found tutorials on finding it, but these tutorials don't seem to work. They said to go to `Control Panel - System and Security - System` then scroll down to `Product ID`.

This product id is only 20 characters and broken up into 4 parts. However, the product key windows is asking me for is 25 characters and 5 parts. I thought it would be the same. Are they the same, and if so, should I just change my product ID to match the length of the nessecary product key?

Comment: I forgot, FYI i currently run windows 10

Comment: Have you tried running Belarc Advisor?  It will give you both versions.

Comment: Belarc Advisor says it's unavalible. I did install that software. I already tried that.

Comment: If you know of any website that has free product keys, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Your license key is located on the COA sticker that came with your OEM device and/or license purchase

Comment: Where would that be. I have an hp pavilion notebook